# What do I need to do to increase model accuracy in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to ML and I have a custom data set that has court cases. The columns are charges(str), prior cases(int) and bond amount(int). I am using charges and prior cases as features and the bond amount is my label. I want to be able to predict what the bond would be given the charges and the prior cases. I am using MLPClassifier as my model and have used a couple others. I am only getting around 45% percent accuracy. How can I increase it? Do I just need to try different models like KNN? Is there a problem with how I am transforming the data? Trial and error have driven me here.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# Bring in CSV
final_df = pd.read_csv('merge.csv')

# Drops bonds rows with bonds over $10,000
outlier = final_df[final_df.bond >= 10000].index
final_df.drop(outlier, inplace=True)

# Gets features from CSV
X = final_df[['prior_cases', 'charges']].values
# Gets labels from CSV
y = final_df[['bond']].values

le = LabelEncoder()
# Transform X data
for i in range(len(X[0])):
    X[:, i] = le.fit_transform(X[:, i])
# Transform y data
for i in range(len(y[0])):
    y[:, i] = le.fit_transform(y[:, i])

# Splits the data, 80% for training
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, train_size=0.8)

# Defines model that the data is trained on
model = MLPClassifier(activation='relu', solver='adam', hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), random_state=1, max_iter=500)

# Trains the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Gives what the predicted label should be
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

# Accuracy of the model
acc = accuracy_score(predictions, y_test)

print('actual:----', le.inverse_transform(y_test[100]))
print('predictions:', le.inverse_transform(predictions[100].reshape(-1,1)))
print('accuracy: ', acc)
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered without understanding the data set you are using. Also, I suggest to take this question to: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ as it is more data science specific question. Better parameter tuning and feature engineering should help you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro & **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of things causing low accurate percentage. I list some common things below.

**Data**

1. The data you're using might not be suitable for the model you chose.
2. Your data might not be clean enough to make the model perform the high accuracy.
3. You might need to explore different aspects of your data using some feature engineering techniques. These are also known as trial-and-error techniques where you create different features and use your model to evaluate it.

**Model**

1. Your model might not be suitable for the type of data that you're using. For example, some models prefer discrete values rather than continuous values or vice versa.
2. The hyperparameters that you chose might not be the best one. This requires the tuning process where you try a set of different parameters in your model.

**Evaluation**

1. Assuming that your data is good and your model is suitable for your data, but the metric that you're using might not be the correct one for evaluating your model.
2. If your model is built for a classification problem, you might need to double-check whether the data that you will use for testing is clean or not.

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question but could you elaborate? What do you mean by the metric I am using might not be correct? I understand you mean the accuracy score but what else would I do?

Comment: Generally, different models have different evaluation metrics. So, the mean accuracy is not the only option. For example, when evaluating neural networks for a classification problem, you might need to use precision and recall metrics or the AUC or ROC plot to measure the learning rate. Another example of unsupervised learning, you might need to use the combination of ranking and other metrics.

My answer is for general machine learning models. Based on this, I think you can search for different parts when you're learning.

Comment: Those are all words I've heard but don't know what they mean yet. Will go and learn them now thanks for the verbose comments.

Comment: No worries, I have some recommended resources if you want to learn more. (1) "
Introduction to Machine Learning with Python" book written by Andreas. (2) Towards Data Science medium website. (3) freeCodeCamp. (4) Kaggle